# Texture Painted images suddenly gone gray

Tags: texturing, uv

I was texture painting a scene, and had nearly finished the majority of it, when I suddenly noticed that all but the texture I was working on had gone a solid colour.  (The greyish textures were grey, the wood textures were brown, etc).

I've saved and reloaded my .blend, I've saved out the textures, but they were the same colour.

However, I think the textures are still there underneath or somewhere, because in the UV editor and material windows, the thumbnails for the textures and materials still show as they did before.

I've uploaded the .blend file, is that enough?

[image: An image anyway!]

In the above image, the arrows point at the solid colour pillars that were texturd, the chest which had some texturing, but now just has materials, the lampstand which is just solid colour, and the banner, which still holds its texture.

in the .blend below, you should (hopefully) see that the pillars, floor, lampstands, and what I did paint of the chest are just a solid colour now. However, the banner on the wall still holds its texture.

[LINK to .blend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1imfaplNU2W2v9DH22XwsNj6Pihw-pm3-)

Any and all help is appreciated!

UPDATE: After looking a bit further, it appears that Blender has some somehow changed all those textures into generated ones, and gotten rid of those old ones. However, I think they are still there somewhere, because they're still appearing as thumbnails for the materials.

If not, then I guess the answer is to just retexture them all again :(.

Anyone with answers to above is still welcome, and also any ideas as to *why* they suddenly all got wiped...

Comment: Hello. I don't use the 2.8 version, but I think it should be some image node with non-color data enabled instead of color.

Comment: Will check that out, but the thing is, it's not just the material, it's the image itself.